# Invoke-SqlServerQuery uses wrong domain and username

Tags: sql-server, powershell

For some reason, Invoke-SqlServerQuery from the InvokeQuery module is using the wrong username for integrated security.  Example:

```
PS C:\> whoami
desktop-7htqmm0\horizon-vm
PS C:\> $env:USERNAME
HORIZON-VM
PS C:\> [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
DESKTOP-7HTQMM0\HORIZON-VM
PS C:\> Invoke-SqlServerQuery -Sql "SELECT * FROM table1" -ConnectionString "server=DESKTOP-7HTQMM0\SQLEXPRESS;database=test1;integrated security=sspi;"
Invoke-SqlServerQuery : Cannot open database "test1" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\<redacted_email>@gmail.com'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-SqlServerQuery -Sql "SELECT * FROM table1" -ConnectionString " ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-SqlServerQuery], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,InvokeQuery.InvokeSqlServerQuery
```

However, the SqlPs module functions fine:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance DESKTOP-7HTQMM0\SQLEXPRESS -Database test -Query "SELECT * FROM table1"

pk                                   someint somestring     somedatetime
--                                   ------- ----------     ------------
7a836fe1-dda6-4496-8af8-065cf45e4922     213 hey hey hey    9/10/2018 9:09:50 PM
7cb4a34d-74be-4c4b-9ffe-35a076d1c018     321 yo yo yo       9/10/2018 9:09:50 PM
92bae90e-8101-428e-bea3-69c520f6c1d8     123 blah blah blah 9/10/2018 9:09:50 PM
```

Table is generated via this query after the database is created (this is from [InvokeQuery's Github](https://github.com/ctigeek/InvokeQueryPowershellModule)):

```
use [test]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
  [pk] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
  [someint] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [somestring] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
  [somedatetime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([pk] ASC)
)
GO
--Seed data
insert into table1 values (NEWID(), 123, 'blah blah blah', GETDATE())
insert into table1 values (NEWID(), 321, 'yo yo yo', GETDATE())
insert into table1 values (NEWID(), 213, 'hey hey hey', GETDATE())
```

Barring the workaround for creating a SQL user for this purpose, I'd like to get integrated security working properly.  How can I get it to use the correct name for the current user?

Comment: Where is the redacted email coming from?  Is it something tied to your desktop, the server, where else do u use it?

Comment: Are you using Azure AD?

Comment: I don't know where it's coming from.  I know it's the account I activate Windows 10 Pro with.  I am not using AD.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... pretty sure I've had this exact problem before.  Look at this [article](https://www.sqlshack.com/connecting-powershell-to-sql-server-using-a-different-account/)

The ‘invoke-sql‘ cmdlet is goofy.

Comment: This doesn't address the use of Invoke-SqlServerQuery from the InvokeQuery module in any capacity.  I want it to run as my current user, as well, not a different user.